# How to add power-LED to my small amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, led

I have a simple PAM8403 that I use to amplify sound,

[image]

The volume switch also works as power-off, if I slide it all the way down it makes a click and its off.

My girlfriend is the user of this device and she often forgets to turn it off because its easy to overlook, therefore I want to add a LED that lights up when its on and off when its off.

How would I go about customizing it to achieve that?

Comment: So you need to detect when two pins of a variable resistor have near-zero voltage between them? And the existing voltage will be the audio signal. I'd impose a DC current (assuming the downstream amplifier can accept a (tiny) DC input, and then monitor the voltage for the presence and absence of any DC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Measure the supply voltage pin of the PAM8403. The supply voltage should be switched on and off the switch. You can just solder an LED with a resistor in series from this pin to GND.
Depending on the color of your LED you have to choose the correct resistor.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the back of your amplifier board you will see you can pick up the power on the switch.

[image]

The Black arrow points to the switched +5V

You would connect your LED as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw0cKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>